# Rewrite an IN subquery as a join

Tags: sql, join, subquery

Can someone help me with this please? Is there a way to rewrite the following IN subquery as a join? Any help is much appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    p.processID
    ,p.processName
    ,p.highLevelOrder
FROM 
    tblProcess p
WHERE
    p.highLevel = 1 and processID 
    in (select processID from tblJobCPR, tblJobTracking where tblJobCPR.cprID = tblJobTracking.cprID and tblJobTracking.effectiveEnd >= @processDate)
ORDER BY 
    p.highLevelOrder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    p.processID
    ,p.processName
    ,p.highLevelOrder
FROM 
    tblProcess p
INNER JOIN tblJobCPR jc
    ON p.processID = jc.processID
INNER JOIN tblJobTracking jt
    ON jc.cprID = jt.cprID
WHERE
    p.highLevel = 1 
    AND jt.effectiveEnd >= @processDate 
ORDER BY 
    p.highLevelOrder
```

Comment: Note that typically database optimization engines will figure this out behind the scenes for you and the queries will run in the exact same time.

Comment: @AndyzSmith Yes, that's true. Though this isn't exactly the case if `processID` can have `NULL` values

Answer (score 0):

If column `processID` is in `tblJobCPR` table than try this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    p.processID
    ,p.processName
    ,p.highLevelOrder
FROM 
    tblProcess p
JOIN tblJobCPR j       on  j.processID = p.processID
JOIN tblJobTracking jt on  j.cprID = jt.cprID 
                       and jt.effectiveEnd >= @processDate
WHERE
    p.highLevel = 1 
ORDER BY 
    p.highLevelOrder
```